# Finding best match in two data sets

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have two sets of data in a file:

```
a a0 x:7 y:7 z:10
a a1 x:2 y:1 z:1
a a2 x:7 y:6 z:4

b b0 x:3 y:9 z:2 a2,a0,a1
b b1 x:4 y:3 z:7 a0,a2,a1
b b2 x:4 y:0 z:10 a0,a2,a1
b b3 x:10 y:3 z:8 a2,a0,a1
b b4 x:6 y:10 z:1 a0,a2,a1
b b5 x:6 y:7 z:7 a0,a2,a1
b b6 x:8 y:6 z:9 a2,a1,a0
b b7 x:7 y:1 z:5 a2,a1,a0
b b8 x:8 y:2 z:3 a1,a0,a2
b b9 x:10 y:2 z:1 a1,a2,a0
b b10 x:6 y:4 z:5 a0,a2,a1
b b11 x:8 y:4 z:7 a0,a1,a2
```

I have to find the best possible matching lines in set B for each line in set A without repeating any of them - the match has to be done base on the x,y,z values. I have to consider that set B has "preferable" lines which have priority before the values.

So this is how I started approaching this:

```
public struct SetValues
        {
            public string x;
            public string y;
            public string z;
        }
        public static Dictionary<string, SetValues>[] ReadFile(string fileName)
        {
            Dictionary<string, SetValues>[] dictionary = new Dictionary<string, SetValues>[]{
                new Dictionary<string, SetValues>(),
                new Dictionary<string, SetValues>()
            };
            string[] fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            string[] delimitersDict1 = new string[] { "a ", " ", " ", " " };
            string[] delimitersDict2 = new string[] { "b ", " ", " ", " " };

            foreach (string line in fileLines)
            {
                if (line != string.Empty)
                {
                    char[] str = line.ToCharArray();

                    if (str[0].ToString() == "a")
                    {
                        string[] tmp = line.Split(delimitersDict1, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        dictionary[0].Add(tmp[1], new SetValues { x = tmp[2], y = tmp[3], z = tmp[4] });
                    }
                    else if (str[0].ToString() == "b")
                    {
                        string[] tmp = line.Split(delimitersDict2, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        dictionary[1].Add(tmp[1], new SetValues { x = tmp[2], y = tmp[3], z = tmp[4] });
                    }
                }
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
```

This is all what I have so far - 2 Dictionaries with line name as a key and value (x,y,z).

My question is: should I recognize some common algorithm in here ? 
What would be the simplest path to go to solve this problem ? 
I'm starting with C# so I would appreciate some easy to understand tips or references :)

I forgot to add that I have the expected output which should look like that:

```
a2
    b6  a2:128 a1:31 a0:188
    b3  a2:120 a0:171 a1:31
    b10 a0:120 a2:86 a1:21
    b0  a2:83 a0:104 a1:17 
a1
    b9  a1:23 a2:86 a0:94
    b8  a1:21 a0:100 a2:80
    b7  a2:75 a1:20 a0:106
    b1  a0:119 a2:74 a1:18 
a0
    b5  a0:161 a2:112 a1:26
    b11 a0:154 a1:27 a2:108
    b2  a0:128 a2:68 a1:18
    b4  a0:122 a2:106 a1:23
```

Where I figured value of `a2:128` comes from `(a2 x * b6 x)  + (a2 y * b6 y) + (a2 z * b6 z)`

Comment: What the criterion of how good a match is? Is it something like `abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2) + abs(z1 - z2)`?

Comment: I edited the post and this is all I know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing seems to be a [matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in which you're trying to find the minimum-cost matching between the A data set and the B data set.

You can formulate this problem as a min-cost matching as follows. For each entry in the A list, compute the "cost" of matching it with some element from the B data set. This forms a bipartite graph where all the A elements are in the first class and all the B elements are in the second class. From there, you can use any min-cost matching algorithm you'd like to find the optimal assignment of A's to B's.

Hope this helps!